# Seemingly erroneous "Undeclared Identifier" for header file

Tags: c++11, sfml

I have the following files:

Source.cpp

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "SpriteControl.h"
using namespace sf;
int main(int argc, char ** argv){...}
```

SpriteControl.cpp

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "SpriteControl.h"
using namespace sf;

SpriteControl::SpriteControl(){}

SpriteControl::SpriteControl(Texture textureIn){
texture = textureIn;}

SpriteControl::~SpriteControl(){}

void SpriteControl::setMoveable(bool in) {
isMoveable = in;}

void SpriteControl::setVelocity(float vx, float vy) {
if (isMoveable) {
    velocity.x = vx;
    velocity.y = vy;
    }
}

Vector2f SpriteControl::getVelocity() {
return velocity;}
```

SpriteControl.h

```
#pragma once
class SpriteControl{

    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    bool isMoveable;
    Vector2f velocity;

public:
    SpriteControl();
    SpriteControl(Texture textureIn);
    ~SpriteControl();

    Vector2f getVelocity();
    void setMoveable(bool in);
    void setVelocity(float vx, float vy);

};
```

When I try to build, I get undeclared identifier errors for "texture" and "velocity", as well as "overloaded member function not found" for my constructor, "left of .x must have class/struct/union", "getVelocity is not a member of SpriteControl", and so on.  An error for almost every line of both the SpriteControl.cpp and SpriteControl.h files, none of which make any sense.  Any thoughts?

Note:  the SFML libraries have all be linked properly.  Earlier, simpler versions of the program without any header files compiled and ran just fine.

Comment: You need to change include ordering. Texture is declared in SFML header and is used in your headers/sources, so include SFML headers first.

Comment: I switched the order, no change.  By the way, none of these errors actually show up in IntelliSense before I try building - they only appear at compile time.

Comment: Your header file probably can't see Texture, Vector2f, etc since they are defined in namespace sf.

Comment: Fantastic, a combination of both answers worked!  So, when people say "headers simply copy and paste their text into the #include position", they're being a bit disingenuous.  The header still has to be able to locate the resources it's declaring.  Thanks so much for the help gentlemen!